# jQuery to show/hide required password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsfiddle

I have a form to change the personal details of the user. In this form I allow the user to change their email and/or password. With jQuery I want to show a 'Current Password' field when it detects that one of these fields is changed.

For the email field this means that when it is changed the password field appears, but when the email is re-entered correctly it hides itself again.

For the password field this means it simply shows when anything is typed inside the field.

I got the basics working, but I can't get them to work with each other. So when I change both and change one back, the Current Password field hides itself.

```
let requiredSet;

$('.js-show-target-on-change').on('input', function() {
  const target = $('.js-show-target-on-change__target');
  let currentValue = $(this).val();

  if ( $(this).data('type') === 'email' ) {
    const emailValue = $(this).data('value');

    if ( currentValue !== emailValue && !requiredSet === true ) {
      target.show();
      target.find('input').prop('required', true);

      requiredSet = true;
    } else if ( currentValue === emailValue ) {
      target.hide();
      target.find('input').prop('required', false);

      requiredSet = false;
    }
  } else {
    if ( !requiredSet === true ) {
      target.show();
      target.find('input').prop('required', true);

      requiredSet = true;
    } else if ( !currentValue.length ) {
      target.hide();
      target.find('input').prop('required', false);

      requiredSet = false;
    }
  }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79fkw3rm/)

Would love some help with this since I've been stuck for so long... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't make decision on individual fields. Think bigger, make decision based on all fields. Use the fields just to trigger a function that decides whether to show password field or not.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dqp7njea/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/dznq36jg/8/

Comment: Thanks all! I feel @doberkofler really aced it with his answer. So I marked it as the correct answer. But the ones above also work perfectly so I gave all an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Here's a description of how the code works:

```
cost email = $('#email').val() // get the starting value of the email 
                               // field to check if it has changed
$('.js-show-target-on-change').on('input', function(){

    const f = $('#email').val() !== email 
        // check if the old email value is different than the new email value

        || $('#newPassword').val().length > 0 
        // check if there is text in the new password field

        ? 'show' : 'hide'; 
        // if one of the above statements are true,show the field, else hide it

    $('.js-show-target-on-change__target')[f](); 
    // update the field based on the above condition
});
```

---

If I understood your use case correctly the following code should do the job:

```
const email = $('#email').val();
$('.js-show-target-on-change').on('input', function() {
  const f = $('#email').val() !== email || $('#newPassword').val().length > 0 ? 'show' : 'hide';
  $('.js-show-target-on-change__target')[f]();
});
```

Comment: Oh wow this works perfectly, and with 5 lines of code in stead of 30!
I have to admit I don't understand half of it, but I'm going to spend the remainder of the day figuring it out. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I tried to keep it short to emphasize on the solution. If I got it right, it basically just does 2 things. It first saves the original password, so we can later compare to it. In the event handler i then just retrieve the values of the email and the password and check if the email has changed or the password is not empty. What might look unusual is most likely the `[f]()` but it's only one of the many JavaScript tricks that allows to keep thinks short. At the end `[f]() only executes the method `show` or `hide` on the element returned by `$('.js-show-target-on-change__target')`.

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested in my comment. Good job!

Comment: No need to apologize @doberkofler, you nailed it and this explanation makes it 100% clear for me, so thanks again!

Comment: @NawedKhan I was about to respond to your original comment, you where totally right of course. I'm fairly new at javascript so I will definitely keep your comment in mind for the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute to specify the input value has been changed and later use that attribute to toggle the visibility of the input element.

```
$('.js-show-target-on-change').on('input', function() {
  const target = $('.js-show-target-on-change__target');
  let currentValue = this.value;

  // if input is email
  if (this.id === 'email') {
    // get default value
    let defValue = $(this).data('value');
    // set attribute value based on old and default value
    $(this).attr('data-changed', defValue !== currentValue);
  } else {
    // if password field then set attribute based on length
    $(this).attr('data-changed', currentValue.length > 0);
  }

  // check number of changed fields 
  let visible = $('input[data-changed="true"]').length > 0;

  // toggle based on the value
  target.toggle(visible);
  target.find('input').prop('required', visible);

});
```

```js
$('.js-show-target-on-change').on('input', function() {
  const target = $('.js-show-target-on-change__target');
  let currentValue = this.value;

  // if input is email
  if (this.id === 'email') {
    // get default value
    let defValue = $(this).data('value');
    // set attribute value based on old and default value
    $(this).attr('data-changed', defValue !== currentValue);
  } else {
    // if password field then set attribute based on length
    $(this).attr('data-changed', currentValue.length > 0);
  }

  // check number of changed fields 
  let visible = $('input[data-changed="true"]').length > 0;

  // toggle based on the value
  target.toggle(visible);
  target.find('input').prop('required', visible);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="c-form">
  <div class="c-form__row">
    <label class="c-form__label" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="c-form__field">
      <div class="c-input__control">
        <input required class="c-input js-show-target-on-change" data-type="email" type="email" id="email" name="email" value="info@johndoe.com" data-value="info@johndoe.com">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="c-form__row">
    <label class="c-form__label" for="newPassword">New password</label>
    <div class="c-form__field">
      <div class="c-input__control">
        <input class="c-input js-show-target-on-change" type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="c-form__row js-show-target-on-change__target" style="display: none;">
    <label class="c-form__label" for="currentPassword">
      Current password
      <span class="u-warning">(required to change email or password)</span>
    </label>
    <div class="c-form__field">
      <div class="c-input__control">
        <input class="c-input" type="password" id="currentPassword" name="password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="c-form__submit">
    <button class="c-button c-button--fullwidth" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for much for the answer! Studying this really made it click what I was doing wrong. Thanks!